# Creating a sub-window with PyGTK

Tags: python, user-interface, pygtk

Im using PyGTK to create a gui in python and I cant figure out how to make make a sub-window. For example I have my main window:

```
class Main(Gtk.Window):
    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self, title="GCT")

        self.box = Gtk.Box()
        self.set_default_size(300, 300)
        self.set_position(Gtk.WindowPosition.CENTER)
        self.table = Gtk.Table(6, 5)

        self.button = Gtk.Button("sub-window")
        self.table.attach(self.button, 0, 2, 0, 1)

        self.box.add(self.table)
        self.add.(self.box)
        self.show_all()
```

When I click the sub-window button I would like to launch an new window independent from my main window and that will allow me to still operate the main window without closing the sub-window. How would I be able to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from gi.repository import Gtk

class AnotherWindow(Gtk.Window):
    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self, title="GCT")
        self.connect("destroy", lambda x: Gtk.main_quit())

        self.add(Gtk.Label("This is another window"))
        self.show_all()



class Main(Gtk.Window):
    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self, title="GCT")
        self.connect("destroy", lambda x: Gtk.main_quit())

        self.box = Gtk.Box()
        self.set_default_size(300, 300)
        self.set_position(Gtk.WindowPosition.CENTER)
        self.table = Gtk.Table(6, 5)

        self.button = Gtk.Button("sub-window")
        self.button.connect("clicked", self.open_window)
        self.table.attach(self.button, 0, 2, 0, 1)

        self.box.add(self.table)
        self.add(self.box)
        self.show_all()

    def open_window(self, win):
        subw = AnotherWindow()


def main():
    m = Main()
    Gtk.main()
    return 0

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Each time you click on the sub_window button, another window will open. They will be piled on each other, so you won't see much :-)

You should always add the connect to the destroy action - else the mainloop of Gtk will never stop, and you won't get control back to the keyboard.